# Control green-blue deployment kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, deployment

I'm completely new to Kubernetes, I'm a bit lost of were to search. I would like to have blue-green deployment between with a web application solution. I've been told that the blue pods are destroyed when there is no user session anymore associated to the blue pods. Is this right? In some web pages I'm reading that there is a flip between one and the other.
Is it mandatory to use the session? In my case I've got a stateless application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Blue Green Deployment**

Blue Green deployment is not a standard feature in Kubernetes. That means that there are many different 3rd party products for this, or patterns. And all products and pattern differ in **how** they do this.

**Example:** [Zero-downtime Deployment in Kubernetes with Jenkins](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/04/30/zero-downtime-deployment-kubernetes-jenkins/) is using two `Deployment` with different `labels` and *update* the `Service` to point to the other service for *switching*. It is not the easiest strategy to get right.

**Stateless**

> In my case I've got a stateless application

This is great! With a **stateless** app, is is much easier to get the deployment strategy as you want.

**Default Deployment Strategy**

The default deployment strategy for `Deployment` (stateless workload) is *Rolling Deployment* and if that fits your needs, it is the easiest deployment strategy to use.